# How to convert 70dpi image to 300dpi?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am developing a PHP app where user will create the image using front end tools.

After user finish creating image he/she will upload to server.

But the image comes to server is only 70dpi.

I have to convert it to 300dpi image.

Is it possible with php script to do?

Or there is another php web server solution to this?

Please help me...........

I have tried this code....

```
$image = new Imagick('source.jpg');
$image->setImageResolution(300,300);
$image->resampleImage(300,300,Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
$image->writeImage('out.jpg');
```

but no output...no result at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers by @emcconville works.

Try to cache the data in php buffers and then print it.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) class, you can increase the dpi from 70 to 300 by setting resolution & resample the image.

```php
<?php

$image = new Imagick('source.jpg');
$image->setImageResolution(300,300);
$image->resampleImage(300,300,Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
$image->writeImage('out.jpg');
```

Although, sampling-up may not increase image quality.